# How do I create a Rust clap derive boolean flag that is defaulted to true and can be disabled

Tags: rust, rust-clap

I have a dry run flag in my rust app defined as. I would like to have a boolean flag that is defaulted to true and must be explicitly set to false for an action to be performed. To get this I tried to use, `#[arg(long, default_value_t = true)]`.

```rust
#[derive(clap::Args)]
pub struct Args {
    /// List of patterns that match files that should be deleted.
    #[arg(long, default_value = "")]
    pub delete_pattern: Vec<String>,
    /// If false, will perform the delete based on the pattern filtering provided by --delete_pattern.
    #[arg(long, default_value_t = true)]
    pub dry_run: bool,
}
```

It turns out that `#[arg(long, default_value_t = true)]` may not be what I expect it to since you cannot use `--dry-run=false`.

```
error: unexpected value 'false' for '--dry-run' found; no more were expected
```

How can I achieve this while still using clap derive? If I cannot what are my alternatives since this feeds into a much larger program that has many subcommands that also use derive structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/_derive/index.html#arg-types) tells you how to treat `bool` like any other `T` instead of specially:

> - For custom type behavior, you can override the implied attributes/settings and/or set additional ones
>
>   - To force any inferred type (like `Vec<T>`) to be treated as `T`, you can refer to the type by another means, like using `std::vec::Vec` instead of `Vec`. For improving this, see [#4626](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/issues/4626).

So just use for example `std::primitive::bool` inplace of `bool` in your struct definition:

```rust
use clap::Parser;
#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
struct A {
    #[arg(short, long, default_value_t = true)]
    f: std::primitive::bool,
}
fn main() {
    let x = A::parse_from(["", "-f=false"]);
    dbg!(x); // A { f: false }
}
```

Usually you'd use `--no-dry-run` as an exclusive and complementary flag to `--dry-run` instead, though [automatic generation of those is still an open issue](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/issues/815).